# Displaying a twitter feed for a company on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter

I am developing an app for a client and they want to show a twitter feed on the app in a small view down at the bottom.

I am very new to the development area with twitter and can't seem to figure this one out so please bear with me. They want it almost like a iAd in a way to show their twitter feed. I have done some googleing and haven't found much help. I tried [this](https://www.video2brain.com/en/lessons/retrieving-tweets-the-public-timeline) but that is deprecated.

Im really lost in where to start so I guess this is where my question starts. Is it possible to show a twitter feed in a "iAd like" banner on the bottom? Will it be very complicated? Where is the iOS Twitter docs? How should I get started? For some reason I just feel really lost in this, so sorry if these are easy questions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to request the Twitter timeline of the company and show it in a custom view at the bottom of the screen.

Example:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"];
NSDictionary* params = @{@"count" : @"50", @"screen_name" : @”YourCompanyNameHere”};

SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                  URL:url parameters:params];

[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                     NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

    if (!error)
        NSError *jsonError;
        NSArray *responseJSON = [NSJSONSerialization
                                 JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                 options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                 error:&jsonError];

       // Show the content of the responseJSON in a view.
    }
}];
```

Here is a nice tutorial that explains all the steps: [How to Load And Display A Twitter Stream In An iOS App](http://www.appdesignvault.com/load-twitter-json/).

[Twitter Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html)

Comment: Is this for atwitter account already on the device? This looks good but I'm a little confused how I can get the companies timeline.json

Comment: Have a look into tutorial I linked. It's pretty much everything there.

Comment: I tried running simulator and it asked me for access to my twitter account on device... so I don't think its what I want